# Google sheet cell delete at specific date

Tags: java, google-apps-script, google-sheets, cell, simple-form

there are some cells in my spreadsheet which I want to remove or delete on a specific date is over . can you help me?
I already installed google script.

java programming , trigger to delete cells in specific date .
waiting for response

Answer (score 0):

```
function deleteOldRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const [hA, ...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  const dtv = new Date().valueOf();
  let idx = {};
  let d = 0;
  hA.forEach((h, i) => idx[h] = i);
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    let dv = new Date(r[idx["COL1"]]).valueOf();
    if (dv < dtv) { // if you only want a specific date change < to  ==
      sh.deleteRow(i + 2 - d++)
    }
  })
}
```

Start Data:

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 |
| 2 | 8/1/2023 | 21 | 14 | 2 | 24 |
| 3 | 8/2/2023 | 21 | 20 | 21 | 24 |
| 4 | 8/3/2023 | 17 | 22 | 23 | 5 |
| 5 | 8/4/2023 | 5 | 24 | 9 | 23 |
| 6 | 8/5/2023 | 16 | 3 | 23 | 14 |
| 7 | 8/6/2023 | 12 | 8 | 16 | 7 |
| 8 | 8/7/2023 | 21 | 20 | 14 | 17 |
| 9 | 8/8/2023 | 18 | 8 | 7 | 24 |
| 10 | 8/9/2023 | 19 | 19 | 18 | 16 |
| 11 | 8/10/2023 | 22 | 22 | 4 | 19 |
| 12 | 8/11/2023 | 2 | 16 | 18 | 1 |
| 13 | 8/12/2023 | 16 | 8 | 3 | 20 |
| 14 | 8/13/2023 | 5 | 1 | 15 | 21 |
| 15 | 8/14/2023 | 11 | 11 | 13 | 15 |
| 16 | 8/15/2023 | 22 | 13 | 3 | 6 |
| 17 | 8/16/2023 | 20 | 6 | 19 | 1 |
| 18 | 8/17/2023 | 7 | 20 | 5 | 24 |
| 19 | 8/18/2023 | 5 | 8 | 18 | 6 |
| 20 | 8/19/2023 | 4 | 13 | 12 | 21 |
| 21 | 8/20/2023 | 10 | 7 | 17 | 14 |
| 22 | 8/21/2023 | 11 | 6 | 11 | 11 |
| 23 | 8/22/2023 | 21 | 13 | 7 | 8 |
| 24 | 8/23/2023 | 9 | 17 | 21 | 21 |
| 25 | 8/24/2023 | 15 | 0 | 17 | 23 |
| 26 | 8/25/2023 | 12 | 17 | 21 | 10 |

End Data:

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 |
| 2 | 8/13/2023 | 5 | 1 | 15 | 21 |
| 3 | 8/14/2023 | 11 | 11 | 13 | 15 |
| 4 | 8/15/2023 | 22 | 13 | 3 | 6 |
| 5 | 8/16/2023 | 20 | 6 | 19 | 1 |
| 6 | 8/17/2023 | 7 | 20 | 5 | 24 |
| 7 | 8/18/2023 | 5 | 8 | 18 | 6 |
| 8 | 8/19/2023 | 4 | 13 | 12 | 21 |
| 9 | 8/20/2023 | 10 | 7 | 17 | 14 |
| 10 | 8/21/2023 | 11 | 6 | 11 | 11 |
| 11 | 8/22/2023 | 21 | 13 | 7 | 8 |
| 12 | 8/23/2023 | 9 | 17 | 21 | 21 |
| 13 | 8/24/2023 | 15 | 0 | 17 | 23 |
| 14 | 8/25/2023 | 12 | 17 | 21 | 10 |

If you wish to keep today, you can do this:

```
function deleteOldRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const [hA, ...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  let dt = new Date();
  const dtv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf();
  let idx = {};
  let d = 0;
  hA.forEach((h, i) => idx[h] = i);
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    let dv = new Date(r[idx["COL1"]]).valueOf();
    if (dv < dtv) {
      sh.deleteRow(i + 2 - d++)
    }
  })
}
```

It depends upon whether or not your date values include time or not